# How root huawei y7 trt lx1/ switch slot?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, fastboot, huawei, factory-image

I am trying to root my phone,

- I unlocked bootloader
- I have uploaded Magisk-v16.6 to internal storage
- I flashed by many twrp versions (fastboot flash recovery TWRP_3.2.3_TRT-LX1_by_kiruha_21.img/ twrp-3.2.3-4-land /
  boot-without-enciphering-data / twrp-3.3.1-0-CRO_U00 /
  TRT-TWRP-3.1.1-0818 /TWRP_3.2.2_TREBLE_TRT-LX1_by_kiruha_21 /
  twrp-3.3.1-0-whyred but every time when I start phone i twrp mode -
  touchscreen not working
- I read https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77597383&postcount=86

And I try to switch slot but when I run fastboot --set-active=a
I get `error: Device does not support slots.`
and when I run fastboot getvar current-slot I get

current-slot:
finished. total time: 0.002s

my fastboot version `fastboot version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04`

Comment: The safest way to use Magisk is NOT to download other TWRP versions ... You need your Stock Recovery & Boot.img files, The boot.img must be patched with Magisk Boot Patcher ..

Comment: Try "Method 2" - Patch Boot Image ... https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-magisk-root-android-devices/

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader must load the DTBO image that is compatible with the recovery image. in your case Touch is not working because the TWRP version does not support it. There is not much you can do, the TWRP kernel must be compiled with touch support (or maybe binary hex-patched).

<strike>Look for dtbo.img or</strike> (edit: dtb is appended to kernel for y7)
use the adb shell commands TWRP comes with:
https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

You can also try to boot TWRP from fastboot instead of flashing it, sometimes this will affect to touch screen work.

```
fastboot boot C:\adb\TWRP_3.2.2_TRT-LX1_by_kiruha_21.img
```

regarding switch slots, you can not switch if you don't have A/B device. don't mix up different recoveries.

please note the differences between **/etc/recovery.fstab**

only in TWRP_3.2.2_TRT-LX1_by_kiruha_21

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata fs: f2fs  
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/  
vendor, product, version, log
```

only in TWRP_3.2.2_TREBLE_TRT-LX1_by_kiruha_21

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata fs: ext4  
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/  
fsc, lksecapp, sbl1, dip, dpo, limits, mcfg, mdtp, mota, oem, syscfg
```

Please check if your phone has f2fs or ext4 file system, and check if vendor partition is present or not. Select the proper TWRP variant according to your partition layout.

you can check your partitions from adb shell or terminal emulator (one of these commands will work)

```
ls -d /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name/*
ls -d /dev/block/*/*/by-name/*
ls -d /dev/block/*/by-name/*
```

for file system type (one of these commands will work)

```
df -t ext4 /data
df -t f2fs /data
df -T /data
mount | grep "/data "
```

Comment: So, What version of twrp should I use? what twrp version is supported?

Comment: the version does not really matter 3.2.2 or 3.2.3 should have minor differences

Comment: When I try adb shell twrp backup SDBOM I get error:
```Setting backup options:
System
Data
Boot
Compression is on
Digest Generation is off
Updating partition details...
...done
 * Total number of partitions to back up: 3
 * Total size of all data: 2229MB
 * Available space: 9877MB
[BACKUP STARTED]
 * Backup Folder: /data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/J5Y7N17718005067/2019-07-12--22-53-24
Can not create '/data/media/0/TWRP' folder (Permission denied).
Failed to make backup folder.
Backup Failed
Done processing script file```

Comment: /data is mounted? maybe related to encryption? share link to `adb pull /tmp/recovery.log` (pastebin.com)

Comment: you can save backup directly to PC `adb backup -f data.twrp.ab --twrp compress data` (the message "Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation" can be ignored)

Comment: When I run ```adb pull /tmp/recovery.log```
I get ```adb: error: remote object '/tmp/recovery.log' does not exist```

Comment: When I run ```ls -d /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name/*``` and smilar that You wroten, I get error: ```ls: /dev/block/*/*/*/by-name/*: Permission denied```

Comment: The touch screen started working when I moved magisk and supersu from the internal storage to the sd card, Thanks @alecxs

Comment: I have one more question,  When I go to backup, a check data, system and boot and I "Swipe to Backup" I got error: Can not create 'data/media/0/TWRP'folder (Permission denied). Failed to make backup folder. @alecxs

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way is to root it with magisk. First you need to unlock bootloader. It can be done with adb and fastboot commands. Then you have to flash twrp recovery with adb. After that you have to flash the latest magisk available via TWRP. latest [Magisk is 20.1](https://rootmygalaxy.net/magisk-20-1-zip-magisk-manager-7-4-0-apk/)